# codeigniter & cjax framework, fatal error class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-2

I'm having this weird error with Codeigniter 2.1.3 and latest cjax for codeigniter. Weird thing is, when I download the latest codeigniter, and latest cjax framework for codeitniger and copy to my friends server, and call:

```
domain.com/ajax.php?test/test2
```

to show the test ajax examples ... it works like a breeze, but when I do this on my server, I get server error (even tho, we both have same php version and such). Server then throws in error log file this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /hosting/www/domain.com/www/application/response/test.php on line 3`

Now, I've read thru stackoverflow with people having this problem and solving by changing the construct and calling CI_Controller instead of Controller. But I already do that ... - I mean it's in the basic example that is suppose to work without touching the code, and it does, just not on my domain for some crappy reason.

**Ajax.php** from cjax framework for codeingter should load controller from folder response, named test and call function test2, which looks like this (the actual file named test.php):

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * 
 * ajax.php?test/test/a/b/c
 * 
 * @param unknown_type $a
 * @param unknown_type $b
 * @param unknown_type $c
 */
function test($a = null,$b = null, $c = null)
{
    $this->load->view('test', array('data' => $a .' '.$b.' '.$c));
}

/**
 * ajax.php?test/test2
 * 
 * Here we are testing out the javascript library.
 * 
 * Note: the library it is  not meant to be included in ajax controllers - but in front-controllers,
 * it is being used here for the sake of simplicity in testing.
 */
function test2()
{
    $ajax = ajax();

    $ajax->update('response','Cjax Works');

    $ajax->append('#response','<br /><br />version: '.$ajax->version);

    $ajax->success('Cjax was successfully installed.', 5);

    //see application/views/test2.php
    $this->load->view('test2');
}
```

I was hoping someone could bring some light into this problem - or maybe someone has already experienced it?

**Thanks for your time!**
Mart

Answer (score 2):

Turn off PHP Strict Standards in your php.ini file.

```
 error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT
```

Answer (score 0):

download the ajax for codeigniter here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjax/files/CodeIgnater/AJAXFW_4CI_5.5.zip/download

the main difference is the ajaxfw.php!!!!